# convert unix timestamp to date in Php

Tags: php, zend-framework2, unix-timestamp

I already referred the questions in stackoverflow before posting this.
In my case I need to  convert 1426023505154 to date format.To makesure the time stamp is valid I checked in http://www.epochconverter.com. I used these codes to convert. But that doesn't worked:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1426023505154);
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", 1426023505154);
echo echo date('d-m-Y', 1426023505154);
```

But all are resulting wrong results such as:

1. 47158-11-20 21:49:14
2. 20-11-47158
3. 47158-11-20T16:19:14Z

Please let me know how to solve this. 
Thanks

Comment: try `echo date('d-m-Y')`; instead of all of this except the first line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your timestamp is in milliseconds and `$date->setTimestamp` uses seconds, you can fix this by dividing by 1000

```
$date = new DateTime();
$value = 1426023505154;
$date->setTimestamp($value/1000);
```

Comment: When I run this code Im getting Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string error. But from your answer I found another solution: 
 $value = 1426023505154;
$value = round($value/1000);
echo date('d-m-Y', $value);
Thanks

Comment: Using PHP 7.4, it works for me without dividing by 1,000.

Answer (score 3):

Try with -

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1426023505154 / 1000 );
// dividing by 1000 because the timestamp is in microseconds
```